# Differences RESTEasy and RESTful web services

Tags: rest

What is the main differences between restful and resteasy webservices? Have been working with resteasy and it works with jboss. That's all I know.

Answer (score 2):

### What is REST?

REST stands for *Representational State Transfer*, which is an architectural style for distributed hypermedia systems, used to build web services that are lightweight, maintainable, and scalable.

The REST architecture was defined by Roy Thomas Fielding in his [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) and should follow this set of constraints:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

  - Resources identification
  - Resources representation
  - Self-descriptive messages
  - Hypermedia
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

The fundamental concept in a RESTful API is the *resource* and resources can have different *representations*. For more details, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707418/1426227) can be helpful.

It's also worth mentioning that the REST architectural style is *protocol independent* but it's *frequently* designed over the *HTTP protocol* because it's largely adopted.

### What is RESTful?

A service based on the REST architecture, following the constraints mentioned above, is called a *RESTful service*.

### What is RESTEasy?

[RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) is framework provided by JBoss to create RESTful services in Java. It implements the [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) (the Java API for RESTful web services).

Answer (score 0):

RESTful is a term, it means that the actual service fulfills all of the required [REST constraints](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), while RESTEasy is a framework for building REST services.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful term refers to those systems that conform to the constraints of REST.

Java API for RESTful Web Services is JAX-RS.

Different vendors offers their implementation of JAX-RS and RestEasy is one of them:

```
- Jersey
- Apache CXF
- JBoss RESTEasy
- Wrapping Up
```