# Web Service, Services & Endpoints

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I am looking for clarification on the definitions of Web service(s) and endpoints.

I have always thought of web service and services as the same thing but I am not sure if this is correct. I have always thought of Endpoints are related to the resource they are retrieving and not whether it is a PUT/POST or whatever.

So with my understanding the following are two separate endpoints regardless if they are `PUT`, `DELETE` and so on:

`/user/`

`/organization/`

And as a collective the application is a **Web Service**.

I have seen others document each resource including the HTTP verb as a separate endpoint and that each resource is a web service and so a collection of the resources are web services like so.

Web Services (Web Service x2):

`/user/`

`/organization/`

Endpoints (two):

`GET /user/`

`POST /user/`

Is there a general clarification or standard that I am missing?
If not what is the common definitions of Endpoint, Web Service and Web Services

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Endpoints and webservices

You can understand *endpoint* as the URL where your service can be accessed by a client application. And a *webservice* can have multiple endpoints.

### REST architectural style

Webservices can use the REST architectural style, which is protocol independent, but it's frequently designed over HTTP.

The REST architectural style was defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy Thomas Fielding's dissertation. And the following set of constraints was added to this architecture:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

The fundamental concept in a RESTful API is the *resource*. Resources can have different *representations*. For more details, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707418/1426227) can be helpful.

### REST over HTTP

Consider, for example, a webservice that exposes the following endpoints:

- `/messages`: This endpoint identifies a collection of `message` resources.
- `/messages/{id}`: This endpoint identifies a particular `message` resource.

Operations can be performed on the resources by performing HTTP requests to the endpoints using [HTTP methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4), as following:

- `GET /messages`: Get all messages.
- `DELETE /messages`: Delete all messages.
- `POST /messages`: Create a new message.
- `GET /messages/{id}`: Get a message using the identifier.
- `DELETE /messages/{id}`: Delete a message using the identifier.
- `PUT /messages/{id}`: Replace a message using the identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are these definitions your own? defined in a book or just general consensus on the web?

Comment: @SJC I've just tried to summarize what *endpoints* and *webservices* are. It's kinda a common consensus.

Comment: @SJC Have a look at my updated answer and let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: @SJC If my answer solves your question, please consider accepting it.