# REST Assured vs RESTful web services

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, rest-assured

Is there any difference between *REST Assured* and *RESTful web services*?

Comment: @molin , thanks for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is REST?

REST stands for *Representational State Transfer*, which is an architectural style for distributed hypermedia systems, frequently used to build web services that aim to be lightweight, maintainable and scalable.

The REST architecture was defined by Roy Thomas Fielding in his [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) and should follow this set of constraints:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

The fundamental concept in a REST architecture is the *resource* and resources can have different *representations*. For more details, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707418/1426227) can be helpful.

It's also worth mentioning that the REST architectural style is *protocol independent* but it's *frequently* designed over the *HTTP protocol* because it is largely adopted and well known.

### What is RESTful?

A service based on the REST architecture, following the constraints mentioned above, is called *RESTful*.

### What is REST Assured?

[REST Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) is a tool that aims to bring simplicity for testing and validating the response of REST services in Java.