# Is REST only for Web APIs? If not, then what other systems can obey REST apart from Web APIs?

Tags: rest, web-services, http

I hear people say as per Roy Feilding that REST is not just for web services. If so, what other systems/mechanisms/anything can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations -- [Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

The problem, of course, is that if that's what you need -- the web is sitting right there, so in most cases it's going to be more practical to adapt to the web as is, and perhaps extend it a little bit in a useful direction.

The alternative requires not only re-inventing the wheel, but also persuading the world to adopt the new standard and use it.

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325558/what-does-long-lived-network-based-applications-that-span-multiple-organizations you are one of the best one who understood REST properly so you might know this answer If I am not wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

Any system that has some type of access to the server, can even be an onboard system that has access to the API network

Comment: I am asking that is it only for web service APIs?

Comment: not necessarily, for example a weather system that sends its data via API could act in this way

Comment: Then it is a web service. I need apart of web services.

Answer (score 0):

Any system that uses URIs to communicate information would be able to use REST.

Example: a theoretical database that fully follows REST rules.

Example resource "serverhost/database/table/1"

Comment: No, this is not a REST because as per Roy Fielding REST is for distributed hypermedia system.

Comment: Imagine my database from the example is distributed over the network and also servers "extra" links and info as REST do, such as other columns / related tables that exist and you access it using 123mywebsite.com/database/table/1 all right? How is this not REST?

Comment: If we can access it through "123mywebsite.com/database/table/1" then it is a web service right. I am asking apart of Web services. (All Web services are APIs*)

Comment: Oh, my apologies. You can access it in other ways as well. Perhaps like file:/// is for local files, you can use database://localhost/database/table/1. Would you say browsing a downloaded pdf with a browser like file:///some_text.pdf is also a web service?

Comment: With which protocol u mean? as a distributed hypermedia system!!

Comment: Not everything is "distributed hypermedia system" that you keep saying over and over again. Distributed hypermedia system is NOT EQUAL to a web service. So my database DOES NOT HAVE TO be a web service. It can be one, but does it have to be? For example I access it using an internal message queue, still using REST principles.

Comment: I asked another question also "What is the protocol"

Comment: Main point: Not all distributed hypermedia systems are webservice. some/url is a distributed hypermedia system but it might use something else instead of a webservice to communicate. Edit: the protocol doesnt matter, for example it might be using my own invented protocol called bananaProtocol://whatever. http:// and https:// are web protocols, there can be many others

Comment: Protocol always matters because it should obey constraints of REST. (I got your point, Please provide me with a valid example with protocol and example that can obey REST and can work over a network)

Comment: You're right, I did some more research and I was wrong. I'm sorry. REST itself says it has to use HTTP protocol. I didn't know that restriction existed. If not for the restriction, my arguments would be valid. So, therefore the answer is you're right. All REST are Web Service APIs. https://rapidapi.com/blog/api-vs-web-service/

Comment: No, the point is not JUST HTTP, we can use any protocol but it should be able to obey the constraints of REST.

Comment: So like using HTTP verbs? I think our discussion has reached the end since we already agreed and stated all REST uses HTTP and HTTP means it's a web service. End of discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217217/discussion-between-xeuron-and-ravana).