# What does long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations means in REST?

Tags: rest

I came across many tutorials to understand each and everything of REST.

**My Understanding -** REST is an architectural style for network-based applications (I mean service available for a client by the server and both communicate each other based on the network)

**is my understanding is wrong?**

What exactly ***long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations means*** in REST according to Roy T Fielding
https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742

I am confused with the term **long-lived** network-based applications.

So if I create an API which follows constraints of REST but not available on the web, but can be accessed within a network (For example, an API to get marks of students in a school but not available in the internet, just available within the school and accessed through HTTP://SERVERIP) - **is this cannot be a REST API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this cannot be a REST API?

No, that's fine.

One of the key ideas is this: that we have an agreed upon standard for the self descriptive messages between the client and server.  In the case of the Web, that standard is HTTP.  HTTP was (for the most part; see [chapter six](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4) for some exceptions) designed to satisfy the REST architectural constraints.  Because we have that standard, we can point a browser (implemented by Google) at a web server (implemented by Oracle) via a reverse proxy (implemented by the Apache Software Foundation) and it all "just works".

If you take those pieces, and put them onto an isolated network that you control, it still all "just works".

> what does long-lived means in layman terms, please...

Roy buried his explanation for that [in the comments](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-724).

> REST is software design on the scale of decades: every detail is intended to promote software longevity and independent evolution.

Pretty much everything on the web understands HTTP/1.1 (1999), which builds upon HTTP/1.0 (1996), which in turn builds on [HTTP/0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) (1991).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @VoiceOfUnreason If possible could you please explain what does `long-lived` means in layman terms, please... It will help me a lot.

Comment: @Ravana long-lived should be understood in the lifetime of the service, that once it is available, it should serve clients for decades to come. The beauty of REST is, that change is inherently integrated into its design so that a server is free to change anytime it has to without breaking well-behaved clients in a REST architecture

Comment: @Ravana if you take a look at standard Web pages, they usually don't use v1 or v2 as this is not necessary. If a server introduces a new property on a field, a client that is expected to send some data including the new field is served with a HTML form resource that teaches the client on the new field as well as on the other fields as well. In addition to that it learns about the URI and HTTP method to use as well as the media type (implicitly application/x-www-form-urlencoded) the client should send the request in. That is basically what HATEOAS is all about